# How to format dates and times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strftime

I'm trying to get make a comments section for a website with the backend written in python. As of now, everything works fine except I cannot figure out how to format the date and time the way I want.

What I am trying to have at the time of posting is either of these:

1. `Posted on Tue, 06/12/18 at - 11:20`

or

2. `Posted on 06/12/18 at - 11:21`

Currently, what I have when the method is called is this:

```
import time
from datetime import *

time = ("Posted on " + str(datetime.now().day) + "/"
        + str(datetime.now().month) + " at: " + str(datetime.now().hour)
        + ":" + str(datetime.now().minute))
```

Comment: use date.strftime()

Comment: See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Take a look at [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format it correctly, from a single `datetime` object, without lots of wasteful small string concatenations.

Comment: Also see [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#datetime)

Comment: And, don't forget that around the world  (which is your audience) there are confusingly different formats for numeric dates. Your example could be the 6th of December or the 12th of June. Always use a text name for the month.

Comment: @barny: Or ISO-8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) which is unambiguous.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It can still be ambiguous when you can't tell from the last two values whether they're 'MM-DD' or 'DD-MM'.

Comment: I may be pedantic but even I wouldn't argue that 2017-12-06 isn't the 6th December!

Comment: @martineau: To my knowledge, there is no culture/locale that orders it YYYY-DD-MM. Sure, nothing *prevents* you from doing that (aside from common decency), but there is no cultural history behind YYYY-DD-MM, so the ambiguity just isn't there like it is for DD/MM/YYYY (European) vs. MM/DD/YYYY (USA). If you see ####-##-## with no context whatsoever, assuming it's YYYY-MM-DD will be correct 99.9999% of the time.

Comment: @barny: I meant some more like 2018-04-05 which could either be April 5th or May 4th.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Like [beauty](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beauty-is-in-the-eye-of-the-beholder.html), ambiguity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Which country uses a format like yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm - do any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to build any format you want:

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Posted on %d/%m/%y at - %H:%M")

print(time)  # Posted on 07/12/17 at - 00:29
```

Read up more on special classes you can use when building your date: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Ah, I can tell that this was posted on 12th July. Or was it?

Comment: @barny - complain to the OP, he wanted a dd/mm/yy format based on what he attempted to do.

Comment: In Ireland, that is how we format it! Also, I have tried this already but it yields this error: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: @Dylan make sure you use the above import line (`import datetime`) and not the one you used in your script (`from datetime import *`)

Comment: yes, you should always avoid from xyz import * - bad style/maintainability

Comment: @zwer I will keep that in mind going forward, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I din't do anything apart from commenting, but it was a pleasure.

Comment: @barny, just with reference to your other comment on format ISO 8601, is this something I can implement in code or just something to adhere to?

Comment: @Shadowranger made that very relevant comment. Not quite sure what you mean, we're talking about how you present dates and ISO8601 is certainly a fairly unambiguous way of doing it: 2017-12-06 is much better than 06/12/17. But arguably for an English-reading audience "6th December 2017" is completely crystal clear. However if you were exporting dates into e.g. a spreadsheet then ISO is the way to go IMO.

Comment: While adding to best practices, if you're going to store it somewhere you might want to use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` to obtain UTC datetime. That way you can adjust the actual date to your users' timezones.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%y at - %H:%M')
'06/12/17 at - 16:29'
```

Comment: Hang on, is that 6th December or 12th June?

Comment: @barny  it is `%d/%m/%y`, so it is December 6th

Comment: Really? I live in the United States and 06/12/17 is 12th June.

Comment: @barny On a more serious note, if you want to see the month as a word, you can use `%b` for `Dec` or `%B` for `December`

Comment: @barny agree, it confuses:)

Comment: @barny If you're worried about this (for example you have to serve dates uniformly across international lines),. you should conform to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which specifies a `year-month-day` format

Comment: Durr. Who presenting a website to the internet isn't (shouldn't be) worried about their audience correctly interpreting a date?

Comment: @barny: Mind you, if you're doing internet presentation, you might just let JavaScript do the work, and call `.toLocaleString()` on the `Date` client-side, letting the browser use the appropriate formatting based on the user's locale.

Comment: Yes, agree that's an even better solution. I'm just fed up with using US-authored intranet websites that use stoopid numeric date formats that work for their developers but not so well for all their audience.